# How to use sem_trywait()?

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

How can I test whether a semaphore blocked?

i try function `sem_trywait()` but it not wokring, i dont now why, can you help me please?

Example is here(Example program that uses semaphores to solve sleeping barber problem.): http://users.dickinson.edu/~braught/courses/cs354s00/classes/code/SleepBarber.src.html

I want use `sem_trywait()` to detect, is semaphore blocket:

```
 void *customer(void *number) {
    int num = *(int *)number;

    //there is my problem...
    //you must waiting to free semaphore...
    while(sem_trywait(&waitingRoom)){
        printf("Semaphore is full you must wait!");
    }

    // Wait for space to open up in the waiting room...
    sem_wait(&waitingRoom);
    printf("Customer %d entering waiting room.\n", num);

    // Wait for the barber chair to become free.
    sem_wait(&barberChair);

    // The chair is free so give up your spot in the
    // waiting room.
    sem_post(&waitingRoom);

    // Wake up the barber...
    printf("Customer %d waking the barber.\n", num);
    sem_post(&barberPillow);

    // Wait for the barber to finish cutting your hair.
    sem_wait(&seatBelt);

    // Give up the chair.
    sem_post(&barberChair);
    printf("Customer %d leaving barber shop.\n", num);
}
```

The proble is in while loop

```
while(sem_trywait(&waitingRoom)){
    printf("Semaphore is full you must wait!");
}
```

I dont know how to use it. Thank you.

---

**EDIT1:**

```
void *customer(void *number) {
    int num = *(int *) number;

    // Leave for the shop and take some random amount of
    // time to arrive.

    printf("Customer %d arrived at barber shop.\n", num);

    if (sem_trywait(&waitingRoom) == 0) {
        // Wait for space to open up in the waiting room...
        sem_wait(&waitingRoom);
        printf("Customer %d entering waiting room--------------------------------------------.\n", num);

        // Wait for the barber chair to become free.
        sem_wait(&barberChair);

        // The chair is free so give up your spot in the
        // waiting room.
        sem_post(&waitingRoom);

        // Wake up the barber...
        printf("Customer %d waking the barber.\n", num);
        sem_post(&barberPillow);

        // Wait for the barber to finish cutting your hair.
        sem_wait(&seatBelt);

        // Give up the chair.
        sem_post(&barberChair);
        printf("Customer %d leaving barber shop.\n", num);
    } else {
        printf("leaving barber shop %d\n", num);
        customer(&num);
        //sem_wait(X);
    }


}
```

Comment: First of all, don't use the return value as a loop condition. The function may fail for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First a general warning, I'll get to your exact problem lower down. Do not use `sem_trywait` unless you have a very specific reason to do so and a very good understanding of semaphores and locking in general. This applies to all locking functions, mutexes, rwlocks, etc. If there's a "try" version of the lock function it's there for very specific situations that don't apply to 99% of the users.

`sem_wait` will wait for the semaphore in the most efficient way possible. You spinning in while loop around `sem_trywait` will achieve almost (but not exactly) the same thing as `sem_wait` except that you'll do it very inefficiently wasting CPU time and possibly blocking others from releasing the semaphore.

`sem_trywait` and other "try" locking functions are there for situations where you can't afford to wait for the lock and you'd rather fail the operation than wait until the lock becomes available. Very few applications actually have requirements like this. This might be happen in hard real-time systems or in some very complex locking schemes where failing is the only way to avoid lock ordering problems.

Most applications don't have this problem. Your example code for example doesn't have this problem at all. The first `sem_wait` will do what you need. If you just want to log a message when the semaphore is taken what you want to do is something like this:

```
if (sem_trywait(X) == 0) {
    printf("semaphore acquired\n");
} else {
    printf("need to wait for semaphore\n");
    sem_wait(X);
}
```

The problem with your code is that you first trywait and after that succeeds, you wait again, this is incorrect since if trywait succeeds it means that it did the same thing as `sem_wait`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that, but I'd like to implement it. that when the semaphore full customer walks, and after a few minutes he returns back. Look at my first post to EDIT1. Is a correct code? If i try to run it, code go to infinite loop. Why?

Comment: Its need to add `pthread_join(num, NULL);` before call method?

Answer (score 0):

Don't test with the while loop. Try waiting just once and check the result.

```
result = sem_trywait(...);
if (result == -1) { 
    // Check one of: EAGAIN, EDEADLK, EINTR, EINVAL
}
```

Then decide to loop if you need to wait more.

Comment: Thanks for your response as you discover the type of error , which is a semaphore is blocked and I have to wait ?

Comment: @gaewouue [Read a manual page.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html)

Comment: I implemented it but every time I get -1 and the program enters an infinite loop..

Comment: It should work then. Add some traces or step the in a debugger.

Comment: I do not understand, how do I check `EAGIN` from `result = sem_trywait(...);` (I'm sorry, it is only now trying to learn from tutorials :-) )

Comment: Did you read the manual Joachim linked to? What does the "return value" section say?

Comment: That means the semephore is 0. The `sem_wait` cannot decrease it. The problem must be somewhere else. You can try looking into the value (`sem_getvalue`) after you post it to verify the value is what you expect.

Comment: @gaewouue sem_trywait() decrements the semaphore if it is successful. You have a sem_wait(&waitingRoom); call following `sem_trywait(&waitingRoom)` which sounds like a bug. If you're having 25 customers as in the link you point to, at least make sure you're noticing the 1 that does acquire the semaphore and not the 24 others that will print out thousands and thousands of lines.